# Floating Cells and a Grid System

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm really hoping that you can help me with this.  I'm trying to create a grid system like the one on pinterest but I also want a left hand sidebar.  So what I need is 2 div's floated side by side, and the one containing the grid cells needs to adjust it's width to accomodate the browser resolution - Kind of like this:

```
[  Sidebar  ] [ [Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell] ]
              [ [Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell]             ]


[  Sidebar  ] [ [Cell][Cell][Cell] ]
              [ [Cell][Cell][Cell] ]
              [ [Cell][Cell][Cell] ]
              [ [Cell]             ]
```

At the moment the the div containing the cells drops underneath the sidebar when I adjust the browser size - Is there a way of making it adjust automatically?  Thank you

Comment: you could place them in li's and float the `li's` left

Comment: Give the right div a `left-margin` the size of the sidebar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. It uses `display:table` to get the job done.

```
div {
    display: table;
}
section {
    display:table-cell
}
.one {
    width:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.box {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:5px;
}

<div>
    <section class="one">
        <p>sidebar</p>
    </section>
    <section class="grid">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mJhGM/

Comment: Please don't just rely on jsfiddle to hold your solution, place it here too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cC27W/)

Sidebar column floated left, and the main content column floated left.

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="left">sidebar</div>
<div id="right">


    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```